# Run .ps1 file on powershell: IP address connection

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and trying to run a .ps1 file in  but am getting the following error.
Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

> [IP ADDRESS] Connecting to remote server [IP ADDRESS] failed with the following error message : The WinRM
>   cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditio
>   transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use
>   winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
>   information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: ([IP ADDRESS]:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionStateBroken
>   PS C:\windows\system32> winrm help config

Comment: Don't post code in images, copy clear text and tag with {}, ctrl-k or use `<pre></pre>`

Comment: what is `ip address` in `$ComputerNames=@(ip address)`? It's not a variable, just a string with a space in between the two words.

Comment: It is actually my ip address, I just do not want to disclose it online

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it requires you to update line 8 with actual computer names. The win rm error is likely coming from the `net use` or `Copy-Item` cmdlets.

I would highly recommend being careful when running arbitrary powershell scripts from the internet. You should break down what each line is doing and understand before executing.

Comment: I removed those two lines but am now getting this error: Service 'ProcessRunnerService (ProcessRunnerService)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start
service ProcessRunnerService on computer '.'.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Comment: @Sophie  It might be something wrong with your computer array.  My best guess is that the '.' separators on your ip addresses are being interpreted as individual items in the array.  Try using with real host names while testing.